# How to use oracle check constraints to limit number of registration?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, check-constraints

I've a user table with unique user_id. User can register using there id. Now I want to limit the max. registration per user using CHECK constraints. so I use this:

```
.... CHECK(select count(user_id) from user where ... ...)
```

But it's show subquery cannot use in check constraints.

Can anyone tell me how can I add this condition?

Answer (score 3):

Under certain conditions, you can enforce table restrictsion with *materialized views*:

```
create table tq84_t (
  user_id   number,
  foo       varchar2(10),
  constraint pk_tq84_t primary key (user_id, foo)
);

create materialized view log on tq84_t;

create materialized view tq84_mv 
 refresh on commit
as
  select user_id, count(*) cnt
    from tq84_t
   group by user_id;

alter table tq84_mv
  add constraint check_max_2_registrations 
  check (cnt < 3);
```

With this materialized view, Oracle checks the constraint on the materialized view when you commit:

```
insert into tq84_t values (1, 'a');
insert into tq84_t values (1, 'b');

commit;
```

This works. The following doesn't:

```
insert into tq84_t values (1, 'c');

commit;
```

It fails with

```
ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
ORA-02290: check constraint (META.CHECK_MAX_2_REGISTRATIONS) violated
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use check constraints on subqueries for this. You can, however, use triggers. A simple use of row-level trigger on a table selecting from the same table and raising an exception on `count > 4` would result in ORA-4901, so you'd need composite triggers for this. But that is a bit of overkill already.

So, I suggest that you might use a separate table with aggregated counts of user_ids updated via trigger and check-constrain that count. Source code:

```
create table user_aggr
(
    user_id             integer not null primary key,
    user_count          integer not null check (user_count <= 4)
);
```

You'll need to create a foreign key reference to the `user_aggr` table on your user table (named `user_registration` in my example):

```
create table user_registration
(
    registration_id             integer primary key,
    user_id                     integer references user_aggr
);
```

... or just creating the FK constraint ...

```
alter table user_registration
add constraint FK_user_registration (user_id)
references user_aggr;
```

... plus the necessary index over the FK ...

```
create index user_registration_i0
on user_registration (user_id);
```

Then you'll need the calculation trigger:

```
create or replace trigger auto_user_counter
    after insert or delete or update of user_id
    on user_registration
    for each row
begin
    if updating or deleting then
        merge into user_aggr T
        using dual
        on ( T.user_id = :old.user_id )
        when matched then
            update set T.user_count = T.user_count - 1
            delete where T.user_count = 0
        ;
    end if;

    if inserting or updating then
        merge into user_aggr T
        using dual
        on ( T.user_id = :new.user_id )
        when matched then
            update set T.user_count = T.user_count + 1
        when not matched then
            insert (user_id, user_count) values (:new.user_id, 1)
        ;
    end if;
end;
/
```

And now you're all set and ready to rumble. Examples ...

```
insert into user_registration (registration_id, user_id) values(1, 1); -- OK
insert into user_registration (registration_id, user_id) values(2, 1); -- OK
insert into user_registration (registration_id, user_id) values(3, 1); -- OK
insert into user_registration (registration_id, user_id) values(4, 1); -- OK
insert into user_registration (registration_id, user_id) values(5, 1); -- ERROR

insert into user_registration (registration_id, user_id) values(11, 2); -- OK
insert into user_registration (registration_id, user_id) values(12, 2); -- OK
insert into user_registration (registration_id, user_id) values(13, 2); -- OK
insert into user_registration (registration_id, user_id) values(14, 2); -- OK
insert into user_registration (registration_id, user_id) values(15, 2); -- ERROR

delete from user_registration where user_id = 2 and rownum <= 1; -- OK; user_id 1: 4 rows; user_id 2: 3 rows
update user_registration set user_id = 2 where user_id = 1 and rownum <= 1; -- OK; user_id 1: 3 rows; user_id 2: 4 rows
update user_registration set user_id = 2 where user_id = 1 and rownum <= 1; -- ERROR on user_id 4
```

Comment: Now you just need to ensure that only one user can log in to the system at any one time...

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, how come? I can see why a single user can't log in to the system by two sessions at the same time, but not why only one user at any one time.

Comment: Because if you allow >1 session, they can both insert rows which will not be visible to the other session, and your trigger will therefore not pick up the constraint violation. Test your triggers with two sessions (and make sure you turn auto-commit off) and you will see.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, I tested the 2-session scenario and I believe that you're not correct. Inserting 2 different users in 2 different sessions into `user_registration` runs just fine. Inserting the same user into `user_registration` in 2 different sessions causes the 2nd session to wait due to the 1st session having placed a lock on the respective `user_aggr` row. After committing the 1st session the 2nd session's `merge` resumes, does its work and the check constraint is properly evaluated. Anyway, I'll be happy to talk to you (via Skype), if possible, so we might resolve this interesting quarrel.

Comment: No quarrel, I see now you are locking a parent row. That's your serialisation point. Nicely done.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, thank you, anyway. You made me think a little more about the trigger and I realized there's a possible (although somewhat improbable) scenario of deadlocking, which could/should be resolved by locking both `:old.user_id` and `:new.user_id` rows at the same time via single `select for update` at the start of the trigger (the `if updating ...` branch would be sufficient) or by writing the two merges as one working over both IDs (somehow).

Comment: I think you're right. Putting them into a single merge would also be beneficial for performance reasons too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use constraints in this case but you may create an updatable view with check option:

```
drop table t;
drop view v;
create table t (counter number);
create view v as select * from t where (select count(*) from t) <= 2 with check option;
insert into v values(1); -- OK
insert into v values(2); -- OK
insert into v values(3); -- OK
insert into v values(4); -- ERROR
```

You may adapt this example for your case.

An updatable view is view which can be treated as an ordinary table. You can create such a view with CHECK OPTION in this case Oracle will prevent you from executing DML on this view which don't relevant to the WHERE clause for this view.

Comment: Wow, wonderful use case of the `check option` clause! I was thinking about writing a trigger for this, but your solution is much more elegant (although error-prone when inserting directly to the table).

Comment: @nop77svk Thanks I like this too although I've never used this approach in my work.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I came up with a counter-example: `insert into v select * from table(sys.ora_mining_number_nt(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));` :-(

Comment: The view won't "see" uncommitted changes made by concurrent transactions, so another counter-example would be to insert two rows in each of two or more concurrent transactions, and then commit.