# How to give a unique constraint to a combination of a column and a fixed value in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, unique-constraint, composite-key

I have a table with with 3 columns: A (number), B (number) and C (boolean).

I would need to create a rule that would prevent records from being created with columns A and B and with C equal to true. For example.

This would be allowed:

```
A  B  C
1  2  true
1  2  false
1  2  false
```

But this, no:

```
A  B  C
1  2  true
1  2  true
1  2  false
```

Comment: Creating a primary key with the three columns does not resolve?

Comment: @Lawrence, creating a primary key with three columns will not allow me to create records like the 1st example cited.

Comment: I think Oracle doesn't allow you create a boolean collumn in the table.But you can try it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679831/how-to-use-oracle-check-constraints-to-limit-number-of-registration

Comment: Encode c=true as c=0 , c=false as c <>0. Insert into c 0 for true, sequence.nextval for false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slight variation on MarmiteBomber's approach, to avoid concatenating the values (which could cause accidental clashes with non-integer values):

```
create table t (a number, b number, c varchar2(5),
  constraint t_chk check (c in ('true', 'false'))
);

create unique index t_unq
on t (case when c = 'true' then a end, case when c = 'true' then b end);

insert into t(a,b,c) values (1,2,'true');

1 row inserted.

insert into t(a,b,c) values (1,2,'false');

1 row inserted.

insert into t(a,b,c) values (1,2,'false');

1 row inserted.

insert into t(a,b,c) values (1,2,'true');

ORA-00001: unique constraint (MY_SCHEMA.T_UNQ) violated

select * from t;

         A          B C    
---------- ---------- -----
         1          2 true 
         1          2 false
         1          2 false
```

---

Quick example of why non-integers (if they can exist) might be a problem:

```
create unique index uq_true on test(case when c = 'true' then a||'.'||b end);

insert into test(a,b,c) values (1.1, 2,'true');

1 row inserted.

insert into test(a,b,c) values (1, 1.2,'true');

ORA-00001: unique constraint (MY_SCHEMA.UQ_TRUE) violated

select * from test;

         A          B C    
---------- ---------- -----
       1.1          2 true
```

... because for both `'1.1' ||'.'|| '2'` and `'1' ||'.'|| '1.2'` resolve to the same string, `'1.1.2'`.

This can also be a problem when combining string values rather than numbers. In either case you can avoid it by using a delimiter which cannot exist in either value; harder to do with strings, but with numbers any punctuation other than a period (or comma to be safe) would probably do - unless someone has a weird setting for `nls_numeric_characters`...

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - your version is still fine with integers, which is all that's shown in the question *8-)

Answer (score 5):

Use *unique function based index*, that process only rows with `C = 'true'`.

You must somehow combine the columns `A`and `B` - I use the string concatenation.

```
create unique index uq_true on test(case when c = 'true' then a||'.'||b end);

insert into test(a,b,c) values (1,2,'true');
insert into test(a,b,c) values (1,2,'false');
insert into test(a,b,c) values (1,2,'false');
insert into test(a,b,c) values (1,2,'true');
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DWH.UQ_TRUE) violated

select * from test;

         A          B C        
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2 true       
         1          2 false      
         1          2 false
```

Comment: I was about to write up something with using a virtual column to store TRUE or NULL and base the index on that column, but this is cleaner and neater.  Nice!

Comment: Forgive me, but instead of Boolean, the column C is a number. But the command worked for me. Thank you.